# How do i using the people API get the list of members of a google contact group?

Tags: google-apis-explorer, google-people-api

I'm trying to get the list of members included in a contact Group. When i try to use [ContactGroups Get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups/get?authuser=1) with *memberResourceNames* as a field. I get an empty JSON response on the API explorer. At this moment, I do not see any other way to get members of a [contact Group](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups?authuser=1#resource-contactgroup).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ContactGroups Get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups/get) is the correct method. You need to make sure to specify a non-zero `maxMembers` param.

Comment: Helpful! But is there a limit of maxMembers ? what if there is a limit, it seems no param for page.

Comment: Thank you!!! I've been trying to figure this out for over a hour!